# Getting return value of syscall in assembly

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64

I'm writing a simple assembly program on Darwin x86_64 (MacOS 10.14.6) that creates a file (test.txt) and writes "E" to it. However, for some reason, the "E" is not written to the file. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my program:

```
global start
section .text
    start:
        ;Create the file
        mov rax, 0x2000005
        mov rdi, fname
        mov rsi, 0x200
        mov rdx, 0o644
        syscall

        ;Write to file
        mov rdi, rax     ;As far as I know, this uses the fd returned by creating a file (previous syscall)
        mov rsi, msg
        mov rdx, 1
        mov rax, 0x2000004
        syscall

        ;Exit
        mov rax, 0x2000001
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall
section .data
    msg: db "E"     ;Message
    fname: db "test.txt"     ;File name
```

I have also tried this:

```
global start
section .text
    start:
        mov rax, 0x2000005
        mov rdi, fname
        mov rsi, 0x200
        mov rdx, 0o644
        syscall
        mov rdi, rax
        mov rsi, msg
        mov rdx, 2
        mov rax, 0x2000004
        syscall
        mov rax, 0x2000001
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall
section .data
    msg: db "E", -1
    fname: db "test.txt", 0
```

Yet neither work.

Comment: MacOS syscall return values are in RAX, with CF indicating whether it's an error code or normal.  You can use `dtrace` on your program to trace syscalls and decode that for you.

Comment: I notice there's no `, 0` terminator on your fname string.  If there are other bytes after it after linking, that's a problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes And if there are not, this could cause the `open` call to return `EFAULT`.

Comment: The file is successfully created, just  nothing is written to it. but  I will try your advice.

Comment: Maybe an EOF is necessary?

Comment: Then use `dtrace` or a debugger to look at the return value from the `write` system call, obviously.  (And verify the args).  That's always the first step in figuring out why a system call didn't do what you wanted.

Comment: @a_random_programmer So the file ends up empty?

Comment: @fuz yes, it does

Comment: @a_random_programmer What does dtrace say?  Try to execute your program under `dtrace` and see if that works.  E.g. type `dtrace foo` where `foo` is the name of your program.

Comment: @fuz I got this as the result: `dtrace: no probes specified`. I  tried with and without sudo

Comment: @a_random_programmer Ah, sorry.  Try `dtruss` instead.

Comment: @fuz I get this error: `dtrace cannot control executables signed with restricted entitlements`

Comment: @a_random_programmer Ah how much I hate modern macOS.  Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476432/is-there-a-workaround-for-dtrace-cannot-control-executables-signed-with-restri) for how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I found  the answer:

I found that opening the file with create mode and write mode works.

```
global start
section .text
    start:
        ;Open file with create mode and write mode
        mov rax, 0x2000005
        mov rdi, fname
        mov rsi, 0x201
        mov rdx, 0o644
        syscall

        ;Now write
        mov rdi, rax
        mov rsi, msg
        mov rdx, 1
        mov rax, 0x2000004
        syscall

        ;Exit
        mov rax, 0x2000001
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall
section .data
    msg: db "E"
    fname: db "test.txt"
```

Also, here is an array of flags for opening files:

```
O_ACCMODE: 0x3
O_APPEND: 0x8
O_ASYNC: 0x40
O_CLOEXEC: 0x1000000
O_CREAT: 0x200
O_DIRECTORY: 0x100000
O_DSYNC: 0x400000
O_EXCL: 0x800
O_EXLOCK: 0x20
O_NDELAY: 0x4
O_NOCTTY: 0x20000
O_NOFOLLOW: 0x100
O_NONBLOCK: 0x4
O_RDONLY: 0x0
O_RDWR: 0x2
O_SHLOCK: 0x10
O_SYNC: 0x80
O_TRUNC: 0x400
O_WRONLY: 0x1
```

To combine, use the `|` operator (in C) or `or` (in assembly).

Comment: Thanks for writing this up!  Yeah, that's an easy mistake to make.  If you don't open the file for writing, you are not permitted to write.