# How do I see all service calls (or syscall) on mac os x?

Tags: macos, assembly, apple-m1, arm64, dtruss

-Edit- Looks like using csrutil to disable system protection solved it. Is there a less extreme solution?

I'd like to see all the syscall/service calls my app makes to the OS. Below it doesn't seem to be logging any calls. I was expecting to see write and exit_group (or exit) like I see on linux using strace.

I compiled the assembly below with `clang hello.s` I ran `sudo dtruss ./a.out` and got this output

```
dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available

SYSCALL(args)        = return
Hello
```

Assembly

```
$ cat hello.s 
    .global _main
    .align 2

    _main: mov X0, #1
    adr     X1, hello
    mov     X2, #13
    mov     X16, #4
    svc     0

    mov     X0, #0
    mov     X16, #1
    svc     0

    hello: .ascii  "Hello\n"
```

Why don't I see the write or exit(_group)?

Comment: @njuffa yes, tries those

Comment: Does disabling just dtruss controls in SIP solve it? See Alexander Ushakov's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476432/is-there-a-workaround-for-dtrace-cannot-control-executables-signed-with-restri/33584192#33584192).

Comment: @GordonDavisson that appears to work ty